# virtuemart canot link media files to products

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using virtue mart 2 that is (2.0.26d)
I cannot link media files to products

I tried uploading images to see if it get linked but doesn't work

[image: when i click on media file and add image it should link to main image it doesnot]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by this. It looks like the media file has uploaded fine. Can you please explain in more detail what you require

Comment: cleck on media file ,the it will take you to media list page where you can add another image after that media should update the number as (2) in the list ...the place where it shows (1) currently!

Comment: Not really. I'm not a fan of VirtueMart at all. Maybe someone else might post a suggestion. You could always check their documentation of post on their forum

Comment: there is a bug i think nobody knows anything about this

Comment: Edit products and go to ->image section ->search from media ->type the name it will show the image select it Done!

Comment: this can be used to show different views to same products hence i needed it badly...thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more image to product
go to product edit page > product Images tab > now select upload radio button and select image and save. now you can see (2) in media for that product.[image]